# Why does reference of an object unable to access method and properties

Tags: c#

Consider the following code in C#

```
class TestClass
{
    public int Int { get; set; }
    public string Str { get; set; }
}

TestClass t = new TestClass();
object ob = new TestClass();
```

Now as per my understanding, both t and ob variables contains the value of the reference of TestClass object. But why is that t is able to access properties and ob is not?

Comment: `ob` does not know that it's a `TestClass`. It _thinks_ that it was just an object.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler determines which methods and fields are available on a variable based on the variable's type, not the type of what the variable contains. In order to determine what a variable actually contains, the compiler would have to do something that is proven to be undecideable (i.e., impossible) in the general case and at least fairly hard in more specific cases.

This is a good time to remember the difference between compile-time and run-time. Compile-time things happen when the compiler is processing your code and generating the assemblies. Run-time things happen when your program is actually running. At compile-time, the compiler does not know what variables contain (you have to run the program for that to happen). It can only reason about what the variables could contain, so it doesn't bother allowing you to specify behavior based on what the variables might or might not contain. Other languages let you get away with this by simply not checking types at all and deferring the process of figuring out which function to call or field to access until runtime. C# is not such a language (with the exception of `dynamic` variables).

Answer (score 0):

Since C# is a **strong typed language** and even though TestClass is an object(since every class is an object), it's a specific object.

An object is the most basic reference type in .net.
An object has only the most common properties & methods that every reference type should have.
Every reference type inherits an object by default, even TestClass. Imagine something like this:

```
class TestClass : object
{
    public int Int { get; set; }
    public string Str { get; set; }
}
```

BTW, You can do these things(if you really insist):

```
object ob = new TestClass();
string str = (ob as TestClass).Str; // will work with casting.

var ob = new TestClass(); // using a var across types.
string str = ob.Str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Object is a superclass of TestClass, and needs to be explicitly cast to TestClass before it can access any TestClass specific members or methods.

Answer (score 0):

All class in C# inherits from [Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx) class , in your case

```
object ob = new TestClass();
```

the ob object is considered like an instance of Object class ( instance of the super class) so it can't access to the property of the class  `TestClass` (child class)

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to consume the properties you should cast the object to the relevant class:

```
class TestClass
{
    public int Int { get; set; }
    public string Str { get; set; }
}

TestClass t = new TestClass();
object ob = new TestClass();

Console.WriteLine(((TestClass)ob).Str );
```

You can find more information about type casting here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is because the difference between compile time and run-time. `Object` would be casted as `TestClass` only at run-time of the application, while at compile time it is still object. Meaning that only `object` properties would be available at compile time, since the cast to `TestClass` actually has not already happened.

Answer (score 0):

You effectively upcasted all the way back to the root class of all in C#, Object. As you upcast, you restrict features, which is to be expected in covariance and contravarience.

Imagine

```
AbstractCar (has turnOn turnOff)
SlowCar (has turnOn turnOff)
FastCar (has turnOn turnOff turboBoost)
```

If you have code that says

```
AbstractCar myCar = SomeFunctionThatCreatesACar();
```

How can you tell if the returned car is a SlowCar or a FastCar without using reflection?

So if you *could* use .turboBoost on AbstractCar, you'd have a chance that you'd call it on a SlowCar which wouldn't work.

You may safely use turnOn and turnOff though as they are part of AbstractCar.

If you wanted you could use a downcast with a reflective check.

```
if (myCar is FastCar) 
{
   ((FastCar)myCar).turboBoost();
}
```

But it isn't really considered good practice as it breaks the "Tell, don't ask" principle.

Comment: Why does it always have to be cars or animals? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: `ob` is of type object, although it holds a reference to `TestClass` object, but at compile time it has no way of knowing the associated members.

[`object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx) is the base class of all **classes** in .Net hierarchy.

> Supports all classes in the .NET Framework class hierarchy and
>   provides low-level services to derived classes. This is the ultimate
>   base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the
>   type hierarchy.

*But remember [Not everything derived from object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx)*

Since `System.Object` is the base class of all classes, the following assignment works.

```
object ob = new TestClass();
```

Due to inheritance, base class object can hold reference of derived class, but it has no knowledge of child members. `ob`'s view will be restricted to only its members.

You may see [Inheritance C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms173149(v=vs.80).aspx)

On the other hand `TestClass` is a child class of `System.Object` *(implicitly)*. It will have access to base class members like `GetHashCode`, `Equals`, `GetType`, `ToString` etc,